# Best way to Create method that accept field Name list

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, expression

Queryable has method OrderBy(this IQueryable source, Expression> keySelector).

I need such a method that input multi key not one key. the OrderBy method KeySelector used for one field, but my method will accept many field name.

I'm created method as follow, but I'm not sure this is best way to do that:

```
class Foo<T>
{
    public void MyMethod(Expression<Func<T, Object>> selector)
    {
        List<string> props = ((NewExpression)selector.Body).Members.Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
       //some work with props
    }
}

Foo<ClassA> foo = new Foo<ClassA>();
foo.MyMethod(u => new { u.MyProperty, u.MyProperty2 });
```

are exists better pattern than this? or this is correct.

Comment: You can use `OrderBy` and after that use `ThenBy` and after that use `ThenBy` and after that ...

Comment: M.kazem Akhgary i'm not problem by OrderBy and ThenBy. I need method that will not accept on Property in each Call. I need to create method that accept many Property in one Call.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible in the current version of C#. Maybe is it possible to apply the same method multiple times for you. Ex:

```
foo.MyMethod(u => u.MyProperty).MyMethod(u => u.MyProperty2);
```

Comment: my solution is work but, I investigate to achieve better solution.